# Chat Application in Xamarin and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xamarin, livechat

I need to Implement the Xamarin Chat Application with My App and also implement the same way in my MVC Application. So Suggest the feasibility and status.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should probably ask more specific questions. Besides that, I don't see a reason why it wouldn't be feasible to program this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can learn something from this project https://github.com/EgorBo/CrossChat-Xamarin.Forms